# Need feature in PR with failing checks

Tags: github, etiquette, pull-request, git, feature-requests

An open source software I am using has a pull request for a feature that I need, but it has never been merged due to failing checks.

Instead of implementing the feature myself, is there any way that I can fix the problems with the other user's pull request?

This question is similar to, but not exactly the same, as these:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944055/fixing-a-bad-pull-request

https://www.quora.com/GitHub-Is-it-bad-etiquette-to-change-someones-pull-request-before-committing

[Open-source, when (not) to go on a crusade for a feature?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6837/open-source-when-not-to-go-on-a-crusade-for-a-feature)

Comment: You can fork the version of the project that implements your feature and create the PR on the master branch; I think this is a solution. PS: I hope to understand your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this problem you can fork the version that includes a feature that you need and resolve the check problem. After that you can submit the PR with your changes.

An example:

There exist a project called A by some developer add the feature to fly over the world inside the fork of project is called A1. This fork A1 does need to define some additional details to be merged to the project A, but noone did do this; so they will live the life in 2 separate fork.

But some developer want the feature inside the A1 marged into A; they can fork the project A1 (let's call it A2) and add the necessary details so that A2 can be merged into A. These details added, they can create a PR.

Now the question is "Where do I create the PR of the fork A2?"

- You can create the PR of A2 directly to the fork A
- You can create the PR of A2 to the fork A1 and it you can join the A1 to A.